# Thread.sleep() and GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, sleep

i just searched on the forum but I couldn't find anything that helps me.. My problem is the following : I was trying to create a little game in which you have to walk right in your friend's back in order to win, the game ends when one of them achieves this..
Here's a simple code I made to explain my problem

I have 3 classes in my application (which belong in the package code) :

- Main
- Game
- Position

I have 9 .png in my application (which belong in the package img) :

- 0.png
- j1_0.png
- j1_1.png
- j1_2.png
- j1_3.png
- j2_0.png
- j2_1.png
- j2_2.png
- j2_3.png

Both packages are at the src root

First class :

```
package code;

public class Main{

    public static Game game;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        game = new Game(8, 8);

    }

}
```

Seconds class :

```
package code;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JFrame{

    private Position j1, j2;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel[][] grid;
    private int largeur, hauteur;

    public Game(int hauteur, int largeur){ // >= 2

        super("Rattrape l'autre");
        this.largeur = largeur;
        this.hauteur = hauteur;
        this.panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        this.add(this.panel);
        this.grid = new JLabel[largeur][hauteur];
        int x1 = (int) (Math.random() * largeur), y1 = (int) (Math.random() * hauteur), x2, y2;
        do{
            x2 = (int) (Math.random() * largeur);
            y2 = (int) (Math.random() * hauteur);
        }while(x2 == x1 && y2 == y1);
        this.j1 = new Position(x1, y1, (int) (Math.random() * 4));
        this.j2 = new Position(x2, y2, (int) (Math.random() * 4));
        updatePanel();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

                boolean over = false;
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
                    if(j1.getY() != 0 && !(j1.getY() == j2.getY() + 1 && j1.getX() == j2.getX())){
                        j1.goesUp();
                    }else if(j2.getDirection() == 0 && j1.getY() == j2.getY() + 1 && j1.getX() == j2.getX()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j1.turnUp();
                }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                    if(j1.getX() != largeur - 1 && !(j1.getX() == j2.getX() - 1 && j1.getY() == j2.getY())){
                        j1.goesRight();
                    }else if(j2.getDirection() == 1 && j1.getX() == j2.getX() - 1 && j1.getY() == j2.getY()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j1.turnRight();
                }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                    if(j1.getY() != hauteur - 1 && !(j1.getY() == j2.getY() - 1 && j1.getX() == j2.getX())){
                        j1.goesDown();
                    }else if(j2.getDirection() == 2 && j1.getY() == j2.getY() - 1 && j1.getX() == j2.getX()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j1.turnDown();
                }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
                    if(j1.getX() != 0 && !(j1.getX() == j2.getX() + 1 && j1.getY() == j2.getY())){
                        j1.goesLeft();
                    }else if(j2.getDirection() == 3 && j1.getX() == j2.getX() + 1 && j1.getY() == j2.getY()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j1.turnLeft();
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                    if(j2.getY() != 0 && !(j2.getY() == j1.getY() + 1 && j2.getX() == j1.getX())){
                        j2.goesUp();
                    }else if(j1.getDirection() == 0 && j2.getY() == j1.getY() + 1 && j2.getX() == j1.getX()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j2.turnUp();
                }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                    if(j2.getX() != largeur - 1 && !(j2.getX() == j1.getX() - 1 && j2.getY() == j1.getY())){
                        j2.goesRight();
                    }else if(j1.getDirection() == 1 && j2.getX() == j1.getX() - 1 && j2.getY() == j1.getY()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j2.turnRight();
                }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                    if(j2.getY() != hauteur - 1 && !(j2.getY() == j1.getY() - 1 && j2.getX() == j1.getX())){
                        j2.goesDown();
                    }else if(j1.getDirection() == 2 && j2.getY() == j1.getY() - 1 && j2.getX() == j1.getX()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j2.turnDown();
                }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                    if(j2.getX() != 0 && !(j2.getX() == j1.getX() + 1 && j2.getY() == j1.getY())){
                        j2.goesLeft();
                    }else if(j1.getDirection() == 3 && j2.getX() == j1.getX() + 1 && j2.getY() == j1.getY()){
                        over = true;
                    }
                    j2.turnLeft();
                }
                updatePanel();
                if(over){
                    end();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

        });

    }

    public void updatePanel(){

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.panel.removeAll();
        for(int x = 0; x < largeur; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < hauteur; y++){
                if(x == j1.getX() && y == j1.getY()){
                    this.grid[x][y] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/img/j1_" + j1.getDirection() + ".png")));
                }else if(x == j2.getX() && y == j2.getY()){
                    this.grid[x][y] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/img/j2_" + j2.getDirection() + ".png")));
                }else{
                    this.grid[x][y] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/img/0.png")));
                }
                c.gridx = x;
                c.gridy = y;
                this.panel.add(this.grid[x][y], c);
            }
        }
        this.panel.revalidate();

    }

    public void end(){

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        Main.game.dispose();


    }

}
```

Third class :

```
package code;

public class Position{

    private int x, y, direction;

    public Position(int x, int y, int direction){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = direction;

    }

    public int getX(){

        return this.x;

    }

    public int getY(){

        return this.y;

    }

    public int getDirection(){

        return this.direction;

    }

    public void goesUp(){

        this.y--;

    }

    public void goesRight(){

        this.x++;

    }

    public void goesDown(){

        this.y++;

    }

    public void goesLeft(){

        this.x--;

    }

    public void turnUp(){

        this.direction = 0;

    }

    public void turnRight(){

        this.direction = 1;

    }

    public void turnDown(){

        this.direction = 2;

    }

    public void turnLeft(){

        this.direction = 3;

    }

}
```

Finally, my problem is this one :

I wanted that, for example, when the Player 1 looks left and he's just on top of the Player 2, while the Player 2 looks down, if the player 1 moves down, it should wins the game, but AFTER displaying the Player 1 looking down.

I tried a lot of input o test, and it seems to work because when over is set to true, then the program goes in updatePanel() and then it launches end() which should sleep for 1 second and then dispose the frame.. but it doesn't, it does launch updatePanel() at the end, it update the value of j1 (as the previous algorithm, i mean the one that assignes values in function of the keyboard inputs, made him look down) but it doesn't display the new grid so, i'm lost :p

Thanks in advice I hope you got the problem, plus the algorithm is easy and not that long so it shouldn't be hard for you guys to understand it :)

Comment: You wrote: *plus the algorithm is easy and not that long so it shouldnt be hard to understand it* . Err, wrong assessment: your put up quite some amount of code up there, with **lengthy lengthy** if /else chains, and nested loops with if ... and a ton of local variables. Such code is **hard** to read. It would take **considerable** effort to digest that, and to then figure what exactly the problem is you want help with. You see, this is not a "we debug your whole program for you" service over here. Maybe some other person has more time/motivation, but dont be surprised if there are only

Comment: downvotes coming in.

Comment: `plus the algorithm is easy` - algorithm is irrelevant. The problems occurs when you execute your `updatePanel()` method. So when you post a question on the forum you post code that demonstrates the problem. So you need to isolate the problem. In this case all your KeyListener logic can be replaced by simply invoking the "updatePanel()" method. In other words forget about playing the game but just test what happens when the game is finished. This is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Use a `SSCCE` with every question, not a core dump of your code.

Answer (score 0):

> should sleep for 1 second and then dispose the frame..

You can't use `Thread.sleep()` on the `Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)`. This will cause the GUI to sleep which means it will not get repainted.

Instead you need to use a separate Thread, probably a SwingWorker. A SwingWorker will allow you to use Thread.sleep() and then you can publish results when you are finished sleeping.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.